# Increment Progress Bar in AppleScript

Tags: macos, shell, progress-bar, applescript

I have an app that is using the "SKProgressbar". I'm looking to have this progress bar increment say by 10 **based** on the process of the second shell script that is running in it.  I am not sure if this is possible.  I have provided the script below.  I am new to this.

```
    on open adisk
    set terminalcommand to "cd " & quoted form of (POSIX path of adisk) & " ; find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete"
    do shell script terminalcommand
    set xxx to "cd " & quoted form of (POSIX path of adisk) & " ; find * -type f -exec md5 -r {} \\; > *New_File.md5"
    set iconPath to ((path to me) as text) & "Contents:Resources:droplet.icns"

    tell application "SKProgressBar"
        activate
        set floating to false --> default is true
        set position to {500, 550} --> default is {1000, 750}, origin point is bottom left
        set width to 400.0 --> default is 500.0
        set title to "CreateMD5"
        set header to "Processing..."
        set header alignment to center
        set footer to "" --> default is empty string
        set footer alignment to center -->  default is left
        -- image path can be HFS or POSIX path, default is missing value (no image)
        set image path to iconPath
        tell progress bar
            set minimum value to 0.0 --> default is 0.0
            set maximum value to 100.0 -->  default is 100.0
            set current value to 0.0 --> default is 0.0
        end tell
        set show window to true --> default is false
        tell progress bar
            set indeterminate to false --> default is true
            start animation
            increment by 10.0
            do shell script xxx
            stop animation
        end tell
        quit
    end tell
    activate
    display dialog "        MD5 Complete!" with icon 1 buttons {"Close", "Open Directory"} cancel button 1 default button 2
    tell application "Finder"
        open adisk
    end tell
end open
```

Any help on this would be great. If the simple answer is no, then I will move on and try to figure something out.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to know the progress of a shell script so I doubt you can do it. In general you'll just have to start an indeterminate progress bar before the shell script and stop it after.

Comment: Thanks. After more research and your response, I found that that is the only viable option. It is better than what I have right now :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with how SKProgressbar works, but if it doesn't reset everything after the script ends, couldn't you reverse this whole process? Instead of attempting to run a bash script from within applescript, why not make an applescript that solely increments the bar by one and then have the bash script call it throughout its code?

eg.

```
#/Users/user_name/Desktop/update_progbar.scpt
on run()
    tell application "SKProgressBar"
        activate
        tell progress bar
            increment by 10.0
        end tell
    end tell
end
```

And then

```
#!/bin/bash
#/Some/Location/my_bash_script.sh
for x in {1..10}; do
    #do stuff here
    osascript /Users/user_name/Desktop/update_progbar.scpt
done
```